# Two async loop inside and mysql query in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to get my info to print in order like this:

[image]

This is what i have so far:

```
connection.query('SELECT `keys`.*,`transaction`.*,`keys`.`id` as kid, `transaction`.`id` as tid  FROM `transaction` JOIN `keys` ON `keys`.`id` = `transaction`.`keys_id` WHERE `transaction`.`status_pay`= 1 and `transaction`.`status` = 1').then(function (rows) {
                    async.each(rows, function (record, next) {
                        async.each(inventory, function (rec, nex) {
                            connection.query('UPDATE `transaction` SET `amount_two`= `amount_two` + 1 WHERE `id`= \''+record.tid+'\'').then(function (err, res) {
                                console.log('3');
                            });
                            console.log(rec.id); /// 4317648454 ... etc..
                        });
                    });
                });
```

But for some odd reason, it keeps looking like this:

[image]

Comment: eachSeries in both cases would fix that, assuming you properly call `next`.

Comment: Could you show an example? Please

Answer (score 0):

This seems because your connection.query appears to be async you would need to break the inventory out of the each loop and process one at a time like this:

```
            connection.query('SELECT `keys`.*,`transaction`.*,`keys`.`id` as kid, `transaction`.`id` as tid  FROM `transaction` JOIN `keys` ON `keys`.`id` = `transaction`.`keys_id` WHERE `transaction`.`status_pay`= 1 and `transaction`.`status` = 1').then(function (rows) {
                async.each(rows, function (record, next) {
                    var count = 0;
                    ProcessRow(count, inventory, next);
                });
            });

            function ProcessRow(count, inventory, next)
            {
                if (inventory.length > 0) {
                    console.log(inventory[count].id); /// 4317648454 ... etc..
                    connection.query('UPDATE `transaction` SET `amount_two`= `amount_two` + 1 WHERE `id`= \'' + record.tid + '\'').then(function (err, res) {
                        console.log('3');
                        count++;
                        if(count < inventory.length)
                             ProcessRow(count, inventory, next);
                        else
                             next(); //assumeing you want to call next when you finish processing the inventory for this row.
                    });
                }
            }
```

You may need to do the same with the 'rows' as well?
Hope this helps.

EDIT: i did not see you calling next in your sample, so im not sure when you need it to fire, but i did edit the post to reflect as if you were needing to call it after the row is processed.

Comment: so, uhm... where is `next` getting called?

Comment: Assuming they wants to call it inside the inventory loop you can pass it along and call at the end. I need to check my sources and i will edit when i get back to my computer in about 15 minutes.